# How programmatically set Row Header DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need a solution without any binding. For example, for columns, I can do this

```
c_dataGrid2D.Columns[0].Header = "vasya";
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and while doing so like this

```
 private void dg_LoadingRow(object sender, 
 Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Row.Header = ("row " + e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString();
 }
```